# Adjusting the content of a txt file

Tags: python-3.x, file

I am trying to filter specific chars out of a txt.file by copying the content selectively to a string and write this to a second file:

```
file = open(filepath, 'r')
file2 = open("C:/.../test2.txt", 'w')
newline = ""

for line in file:
    for letter in line:
        if letter == "#": continue
        else: newline += letter
    newline += "\n"

file2.write(newline)
```

I only manage to copy and mutate the content of file1 by using the newline character after reading each line, but with the effect of having undesired empty lines in my new txt2 file:

```
fewfewfw

fwefewf
```

How do I prevent having to remove these empty lines afterwards? Is there a better way to adjust a txt file anyway?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you are trying to remove all the `#` symbols from the file, use:

```
with open(filepath, 'r') as f1, open("C:/.../test2.txt", 'w') f2:
    content = f1.read()
    f2.write(content.replace('#', ''))
```